# Postgres Issue: prompt has changed

Tags: sql, postgresql

test=# SELECT COUNT(id) FROM person'

test'#

[image]

Comment: Prompt just says that you have unclosed quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` is smart enough to guide us. Look at this simple session:

```
postgres=# select
postgres-# (          -- statement was not finished by semicolon
postgres(# select     -- parenthesis was opened, needs to be closed
postgres(# '
postgres'# abc        -- quote was opened, needs to be closed
postgres'# '          -- quote is still opened
postgres(# as x       -- quote was closed, parenthesis still opened
postgres(# )
postgres-# ;          -- parenthesis was closed, statement needs semicolon to completion
┌─────┐
│  x  │
├─────┤
│    ↵│
│ abc↵│
│     │
└─────┘
```

The whole statement looks like

```
select (select 'abc' as x);
```

without `\n`'s

Comment: Thanks. 
But how do I close it if it's still opened?
I am checking on line and I am not seeing a similar example.